# Regex for variable definition

Tags: regex

I'm currently learning regular expressions and I'm trying to achieve the following:
Given some definition of a variable, I want to get only the "name = val" part.
Example:

```
"int a = 5;" -> "a = 5"
"double nameName_name3       =        6    ;   " -> "nameName_name3 = 6"
```

I tried this : `\b(?!final|int|char|String|boolean|double|;)\S+\b`
but when given for example `"int a = 5"` I get `"a"` and `"5"` in different groups.
But when doing `"int a=5"` I get the desired output (i.e : `"a=5"`).
If someone got any idea, I'd be happy to know, thanks!

Comment: You can match the `=` and the optional whitespace chars `\b(?!final|int|char|String|boolean|double|;)[^\s=]+\s*=\s*[^\s=]+` https://regex101.com/r/ByIMgi/1

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code and it almost gave me what I want: when entering "int a = 5;" I got "a=5;", but I don't want the semicolon at the end. Do you have an idea on how can I fix this ?

Comment: You can exclude the unwanted characters `\b(?!final|int|char|String|boolean|double|;)[^\s=;]+\s*=\s*[^\s=;]+` https://regex101.com/r/Ir63cG/1

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! You can submit your answer so I can accept it if you want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the optional whitespace chars `\s*`, and omit matching the `=` and for example `;` using a negated character class `[^\s=;]+` and repeat it 1+ more times to match at least a single char before and after the equals sign.

You might add a word boundary `\b` at the end of the pattern to match only the word characters.

```
\b(?!final|int|char|String|boolean|double|;)[^\s=;]+\s*=\s*[^\s=;]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGyr83/1)

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
^(?:final|int|char|String|boolean|double)\s(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+).*$
```

Replace by `\1 = \2`.

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGyr83/2).

I used `(\w+)` because in all programming languages that I know the only characters used to name identifiers (names of functions, variables etc.) are word-characters, hence why `\w` is short for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. The 2nd capturing group though could be subject to debate.